# MvxCommand With CommandParameter binding to field

Tags: android, exception, binding, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm trying using fire `MvxCommand` with `CommandParameter`:

```
   <Mvx.MvxListView
   style="@style/MyList"
   local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Items;"
   local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/itemfavorite" />
```

It is my property in `ViemModel`:

```
    public List<Data> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
        set
        {
            _items = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Items);
        }
    }
```

It is my `model`:

```
public class Data
{
   public int Id{get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public ICommand Action {get;set;}
}
```

It is my `command`(using in Data):

```
    public ICommand MyCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new MvxCommand<int>(async (id) =>
            {
               .....
            }
    }
```

It is my `MvxItemTemplate`:
    ....

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    local:MvxBind="Click Action,CommandParameter=Id"/>
```

If I use "`CommandParameter=Id`" - I get unhandle exception. "`CommandParameter=1`" - it is work. But I need to pass a `CommandParameter` value field Id. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value for *CommandParameter* is a **static** value. Unfortunately you cannot use the name of a property to pass as the command parameter.

You got an exception because Mvx was trying to convert the *string* "Id" into an *int*.

Instead of passing *Id*, you can simply use it in your command handler.

```c#
public ICommand MyCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new MvxCommand(async () =>
        {
           // use Id here
        }
    }
}
```